# Android recyclerview can't select single Item

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have list of small images,i want to make single image big when i click on it,the problem is that when i click on more than one image the others that i clicked before don't return to thier small size,they remain big.Can You help?

Thanks in advance.

> Here is how it looks

[Screenshot](http://joxi.net/KAg1yokFXpwD4m)

> Adapter

```
public class PdfAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PdfAdapter.PdfViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<PdfModel> pdfModels;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public PdfAdapter(Context mContext, List<PdfModel> pdfModels, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.pdfModels = pdfModels;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PdfViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.pdf_layout, parent, false);
        return new PdfViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PdfViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CardView.LayoutParams bigParams = new CardView.LayoutParams(200, 240);
        CardView.LayoutParams smallParams = new CardView.LayoutParams(120, 153);
        PdfModel model = pdfModels.get(position);
        Glide.with(mContext).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
        if (listener != null) {
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                listener.onItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                if (!model.isSelected()) {
                   // model.setSelected(true);
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdfModels.size(); i++) {
                        pdfModels.get(i).setSelected(true);
                    }
                }else {
                    model.setSelected(false);
                }
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            });
        }
        if (model.isSelected()) {
            holder.cardView.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.transparentColor)));
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(bigParams);
        } else {
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(smallParams);
            holder.cardView.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.foregroundColor)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pdfModels == null ? 0 : pdfModels.size();
    }

    class PdfViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.page_img)
        ImageView imageView;
        @BindView(R.id.card_view)
        CardView cardView;

        public PdfViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

> PdfModel Class

```
public class PdfModel {
    private int image;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public PdfModel(int image, boolean isSelected) {
        this.image = image;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public PdfModel(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

> Fragment

```
 private void setPages(){
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle1,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle2,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle3,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle4,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle6,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle1,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle2,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle3,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle4,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle5,false));
        mList.add(new PdfModel(R.drawable.rectangle6,false));
        adapter = new PdfAdapter(getActivity(),mList,this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(newLinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
       // mList.get(position).setSelected(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that with

```
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

in onBindViewHolder you only notify the adapter about the item that should get bigger not the one that should get smaller. The easiest fix would be to replace this line with

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This would refresh all items. Another solution would be to remember the position of the currently selected item in the adapter and to call notifyItemChanged for the remembered position too.

Comment: can you write for me the other solution please?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to use notifyDataSetChanged

```
 if (listener != null) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            listener.onItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
  
            model.setSelected(!model.isSelected());
          
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
    }
```